# css alignment issues text is dispalying too below

Tags: css, html, tierprice

please visit these links :

we are using a magento platform

if tier prices are available than its displaying like this :

if tier prices are not available, than its displaying like this :

means ,

this text "10 days Replacement Guarantee" is

displaying too much below.

please help me to make proper alignement as like in first link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really anything to do with Magento, but: On the first page div.replace is outside of div.quickphp, on the second page it's inside it. I guess when 'wholesale is not available' you're not closed .quickphp properly.

Comment: can you please give the updated code to display properly

Comment: No, you haven't pasted the phtml that generates that block, and you shouldn't need to. The branch of the if statement that echoes out 'Wholesale Available' probably has a `</div>` at the end of it, that should be after the whole if statement, not the branch

Comment: i will check it.....